# Трассировка лучей в cyles render

Tags: blender, render

Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой: на сайте blender написано, что трассировку лучей поддерживают движки blender и cycles. В blender render трассировка лучей включается по инструкции на сайте, а для трассировки в cycles эта инструкция не подходит. Как возможно использовать её в cycles?
Вот статься на blender manual: [ссылка](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/mirror.html)

Comment: tl;dr - Cycles и так использует трассировку лучей всегда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте разберемся.

Существует два основных типа рендера: scanline и raytracing, это  Blender render и Cycles соответственно. Оба рендера проводят виртуальную линию через каждый пиксель, определяя, какие полигоны лежат на пути этой линии и вычисляют необходимый цвет пикселя. А вот процесс вычисления этого цвета выглядит по-разному.

Blender render, зная поворот полигона и нахождение в пространстве источников света вычисляет цвет пикселя по формуле указанной в настройках материала, например, по формуле альбедо Ламберта.

Cycles, в отличие от Blender render пытается сымитировать реальный луч света, определяя в какое место попал луч, строит отраженный луч в зависимости от настроек материала и угла падения, затем отслеживает далее путь луча, до тех пор, пока он не встретится с источником света или превысит максимальное количество отражений.

Так Blender render справляется со своей задачей быстрее, но результат обычно не очень хорош. Так например, в нем нет отражений, ведь не строя отраженный луч нельзя просто по формуле построить отражение. Тут на помощь приходит трассировка лучей. Как вы описали, вы включаете ее и получаете отражение объектов. То есть по сути вы включаете алгоритм  аля-Cycles внутри Blender render.

Как же включается трассировка лучей в Cycles? Корректным будет скорее вопрос как ее выключить! Собственно трассировка лучей и есть Cycles, это ядро этого рендера, его основа. Как нельзя отключить scanline в Blender render, или openGL во вьюпорте.

Comment: Спасибо. Чот затупил)